# Why can't we define the directional derivative of vector fields on a manifold in the same way as in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

First of all I apologize for my english, it is not my first language.

I am reading the book "Differential Geometry" by Loring W. Tu. In subsection 4 of chapter 1, Tu defines the directional derivative at $p$ of a $C^\infty$ vector field $Y=\sum b^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the direction $X_p$ as

\begin{align}
D_{X_p}Y=\sum (X_p b^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p}.
\end{align}

When $X$ is a $C^\infty$ vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$, not just a vector at $p$, we define the vector field $D_XY$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by

\begin{align*}
(D_xY)_p=D_{X_p}Y 
\end{align*}

for all $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Later, in subsection 6, which deals with affine connections, Tu writes:

"Consider a smooth vector field $Y$ on a manifold $M$ and a tangent vector $X_p \in T_pM$
at a point $p$ in $M$. To define the directional derivative of $Y$ in the direction $X_p$, it is necessary to compare the values of $Y$ in a neighborhood of $p$. If $q$ is a point near $p$, in general it is not possible to compare the vectors $Y_q$ and $Y_p$ by taking the difference $Y_q-Y_p$, since they are in distinct tangent spaces. For this reason, the directional derivative of a vector field on an arbitrary manifold $M$ cannot be defined in the same way as in Section 4".

My problem is that I don't see in the definition of directional derivative where the values ​​of $Y_p$ and $Y_q$ are compared. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have that to compute the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in the direction $X_p$, we first write down a set of parametric equations for the line through $p$ in the direction $X_p$:

\begin{align*}
x^i=p^i+ta^i
\end{align*}

with $i=1,...,n$. Let $a=(a^1,...,a^n)$. Then $D_{X_p}f$ is

\begin{align*}
D_{X_p}f&=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(p+ta)-f(p)}{t}=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr\rvert_{t=0} f(p+ta)\\
&=\sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\Bigr\rvert_{p} \frac{dx^i}{dt}\Bigr\rvert_{0} =\sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\Bigr\rvert_{p} a^i\\&=\big(\sum a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p}\big)f=X_p f.
\end{align*}

When $X$ and $Y$ are $C^\infty$ vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then

\begin{align*}
(D_xY)_p=D_{X_p}Y=\sum (X_p b^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p}&=\sum \big(\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{b^i(p+ta)-b^i(p)}{t}\big)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p}\\
&=\sum \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\big(b^i(p+ta)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p}\big)-\big(b^i(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p}\big)}{t} \tag{1}
\end{align*}

is this last line right?, I mean, is (1) right? or should I write

\begin{align}
=\sum \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\big(b^i(p+ta)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p+ta}\big)-\big(b^i(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p}\big)}{t}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

If (2) is the right way, then I see why is not possible to compare $Y_q$ and $Y_p$, and the reason is because they are in distinct tangent spaces. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ we do not have this problem, because there are a canonical basis for all the tangent spaces, and that is why we can compare tangent vectors in distinct tangent spaces. But if (1) is right then I do not see why we can not define the directional derivative of vector fields on a manifold in the same way is done in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What am I not understanding correctly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez But, in principle, I could evaluate $(D_xY)_p=D_{X_p}Y=\sum (X_p b^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p}$ on a local chart, where $x^i$ are some coordinates and $b^i$ components of $Y$ in that chart. I tried this componentwise approach but I found it does not transform as desired on a change of coordinates (i.e. if I do the calculation in $x^i$ and then calculate the components of the result in $y^i$ coordinates I find different values than doing the calculation in $y^i$). Is also this a symptom of the problem? thanks (I had similar doubts as the OP)

Comment: @Mariano thanks. Just to check if I got your point, I was observing that if $Xp=D_x$  is my directional derivative (expressed in coordinate free form as a pure tangent vector $\in T_p$ )  I would get the same formula locally $\sum (X_p b^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p}$ . Now, taking a compatibile chart with coordinates $y^i$ with transition function $y^i=f^i(x^1...x^n)$ and jacobian $J$, the components of $\sum (X_p b^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \Bigr\rvert_{p}$ written as a column vector $[X_pb^1,...,X_pb^n]$ would become $J^{-1} [X_pb^1,...,X_pb^n]$ in the y chart.

Comment: Whereas if I first change the coordinates and the take $X_p$ of each component (in the y chart) I would get for each component $X_p (J^{-1} b)_i$  where by $( )_i$ I mean the $i^{th}$ component of the vector. So the two do not match as in the second case I will have terms with derivatives of the Jacobian. Is this what you mean when you mention the Leibniz rule? thanks